# Wordpress $wp_rewrite

Tags: php, routes, wordpress

I've a little question about $wp_rewrite object in Wordpress...

I'm building a plugin which need some routes were not included in Wordpress. So i'm trying to use the `non_wp_rules` action from `$wp_rewrite` object.

Here is my code :

```
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrites');
add_filter('wp_loaded', 'flush_rules');

function flush_rules()
{
  $rules = get_option('rewrite_rules');
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

function add_rewrites()
{
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $rules = array(
    'documentation/$' => 'fileToCall.php'
  );

  $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules += $rules;
}
```

But I don't understand... My route is added with any problem (just a `var_dump` on `$wp_rewrite` is saying to me all is okay), but it seems the file i'm trying to call (`fileToCall.php`) which just contain an echo for moment (so no errors) returns a 404 error in Firefox dev console.

Is there someone who have this problem someday? Does I am doing something wrong?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

wp_rewrite test if redirect address is locale or external. In your case it is external, so you have to use a different function. Just replace your second hook by this:

```
add_action('init', 'add_rewrites');

function add_rewrites() 
{
  global $wp_rewrite;

  $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule('documentation/$', 'fileToCall.php');

}
```

Comment: I've already try this too but the problem is already the same : 404 error. (My file is in the Wordpress root directory).

Comment: And did you try to add the complete path to your filename?

Comment: What i don't understand is all routes (WP included) just call index.php?foo=bar&something. test.php is also in the same directory... i think the problem is not in file location...